# Naming tables returned from Oracle

Tags: .net, oracle, stored-procedures, multiple-tables

I'm using the Oracle data libraries in .NET to get multiple tables returned from a Procedure (as multiple Out cursors). This data is being inserted into a `DataSet`. The problem I'm having is that the tables are named `Table`, `Table1`, `Table2`, etc. Is there some way (through the Oracle data adapter or otherwise) to rename these tables *before* they go into the `DataSet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you need `DataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table","MyTableName")`

See: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings.aspx